# Learning web testing QA

Tags: manual-testing, qa-developer

I am a general student. Nowadays I am trying to learn website testing but where from I will start, where from learn, which process will be better for me. I want to know about it. Please anybody give me some advice for it. This is my first question. so If I do error please correction me.

Comment: Yeasin welcome to SQA. This is not the sort of question that can be easily answered as it is more of a conversation starter. You should start with a search on the site as there is a lot of content already, such as this question http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/new-to-testing-need-direction.

Comment: Thanks Bruce McLeod for your advice, Now I am searching for knowing & also learning about QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test websites I think its important that you have a basic level understanding of the technology. Follow the free courses [HTML & CSS](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) and [JavaScript](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) on codecademy.com.

Reading a book on the testing topic might also be a great idea, see [this list of good testing books](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing).

To get more experience in testing websites you can sign up at [uTest.com](http://www.utest.com/). They have training materials like video courses and they will invite you for actual or practise testing sessions. You can then also monitor issues found by other testers and learn where to look for.

Most web-application testing is automated, the next level could be automated testing with [Selenium builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/) or following a more advanced [online Selenium course](http://university.utest.com/selenium-basics-part-1-how-to-set-up-selenium/).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to read these two books:

1. Patton Ron - [Software Testing, 2nd Edition](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Software_Testing.html?id=8rJQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y);
2. Cem Kaner - [Testing Computer Software, 2nd Edition](http://bookzz.org/book/1269562/080be3).

do not pay attention that they are old, these books cover theory and practice of software testing and also SDLC. After that, you will have a strong basis for testing. If you have more questions, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are searching for help here. When I first started off in testing, I didn't have the slightest clue where to look for help, so my first couple projects were a needless struggle.

I would get familiar with the school of context driven testing. People like Scott Barber, James Bach, Cem kaner, Keith Klain have lots of content that they've shared over the years. Everyone who is influential in the space seems to have their own quirk as to how testing should be done, and rightfully so, since no tester is the same.

Your biggest asset will be critical thinking. As mentioned above, Code Academy is a great place to get some basic knowledge of the technologies you'll be working with. They make it fun too, which is a plus.